# Day Date difference between two date calculation in SQL AND C# producing varying result

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am calculating the day difference in two dates.
In C#

```
diffdays = (EndDate-StartDate).Days
```

so considering the Enddate as 6/26/2015 and startdate as 6/10/2015 the diffdays value is 15 as shown in the Autos section while debugging.

While in SQL server what I am doing is

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate )
```

where EndDate is 6/26/2015 and startdate is 6/10/2015  and it gives a result 16.

I need these two day difference to be same. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: what are the datatime of start/end date of sql sever and c#?

Comment: I just re ran the code and the difference is 16. so i guess it was due to datetime . But how could the answers vary? when the date time is same in both the cases?

Comment: A C# DateTime also contains a Time component. Inspect your Start and EndDate carefully.

Comment: yes ... the date time thing was the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TimeSpan.Days` property returns whole days only, dropping any fractional portion. Depending on the time portion of your two `DateTime`'s, you could expect the behavior you're seeing.

Try taking the time portion out of the equation by using the `Date` property (and effectively setting both times to midnight):

```
diffdays = (EndDate.Date - StartDate.Date).Days
```

Alternatively, you can round up the `TotalDays` property (which includes fractional portions of days):

```
diffdays = Math.Ceiling((EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays);
```

Comment: yes i guess the problem is with date time because the difference now is 16 in both cases. I will try to implement your suggestion and get back to you. thank you

Comment: Bingo thanks mate. How could i have been so stupid. Grr hahahaha.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF` function of SQL counts the number of times you pass the boundary specified as units, whereas .NET's `DateTime.Subtract()` function (you use this function when implicitly through the use of minus operator) returns the actual `TimeSpan` between the two dates, so you are bound to see differences between the two results.

### EXAMPLE

The following query will return 1:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '1/1/2015 23:58:00', '1/2/2015 00:02:00')
```

There is a difference of only 4 minutes between the two dates, but since a day boundary has passed between the two dates (at 12:00 midnight), it returns 1. The same two dates will return a `TimeSpan` of 4 minutes in C#. If you check just the `Days` part (not `TotalDays`) of that `TimeSpan` object (as you're doing above), you'll get 0.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you are calculating the number of days between the two dates. In SQL the `DATEDIFF` function is is calculation the number of days after the first date, including the end date.

To fix this this simplest thing to do would be to add 1 to the C# `diffdays` variable.

Comment: sorry but its giving exact result in other cases. it probably was due to datetime

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code returns strange result ... I created simple console application and variable differ equals 16 as in sql server

```
 DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 6, 10);
 DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2015, 6, 26);
 var differ = (endDate - startDate).Days;
```

Please double check your C# results

Comment: yes now it returns 16. But few minutes ago it was different. Datetime problem

Comment: maybe your DateTime contained not only date but and time. And as @GrantWinney said property Days may be less